# mkvmerge add stream (e.g. subtitles) without copying entire file / in place merge

Tags: video, matroska

The title says it all. I frequently add subtitle `.srt` files to `.mkv` files and every time I use mkvtoolnix / mkvmerge, the entire input `.mkv` is copied to the otput file. Is there a way to do the merge in place, i.e. write the `.srt` file into an additional stream in the existing file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. Adding of new streams increases the size of the file, even if it is something small as a subtitle. This has to be done by muxing/demuxing the file(ie, opening the mkv container and closing it after adding the stream). It has many other reasons too, few are fault tolerance and buffer optimization(optimize the file size after adding the stream).

Whereas you can add/change meta-data in-place as the mkv container allocates/consumes space for them whether or not it is present.

In general no tool can do what you require in place as it goes against the mkv container specifications.